# Contour Integration of Square Root with Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Recently I've been working on branch cuts of square root functions, and come to problems like this:

---

Find a single-valued analytic branch $f$ of $\sqrt{z^2+z}$ on the set $\{ z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| >1 \}$ such that $f(2) = -\sqrt{6}$. 
Evaluate the integral of $f$ around the contour $|z| =2$ (positively oriented) using the Laurent series of the square root.

---

I can find an $f$: the function $-\sqrt{z}\sqrt{z+1}$ where the square roots are the principal branch of the square roots function.

However, the only example of using Laurent series I've seen ([in these notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/stcs/courses/fcm/handouts/branchcutintegral.pdf)) for contour integrals like this works by factoring a $z$ out of a square root; i.e. writing
$$ (z^2+z)^{1/2} = z(1+1/z)^{1/2}  $$
and then using the Laurent expansion for the (principal branch) square root $\sqrt{z}$ about $z=1$ to expand $(1+1/z)^{1/2} $.

My question is about the signs here. The approach above assumes that $\sqrt{z^2} = z$, but it seems that in my branch of the square root, I have $\sqrt{z^2} = -z$.

And then the square root I'm left with in the factorization is still defined based on the branch of $\sqrt{z^2+z} \;$ I'm using, so would I use the Laurent expansion for $- \sqrt{z}$ instead?

I understand that if both signs need to be negative, there's no net effect on the result; I'm just trying to understand the details of the computation. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concretely expand $\sqrt{z^2+z}=-z\sqrt{1+1/z}\ $ that verifies $f(2)=-\sqrt{6}$ (the $+$ possibility doesn't apply).

The cut should be chosen between the points $-1$ and $0$ as in [your linked file](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/stcs/courses/fcm/handouts/branchcutintegral.pdf) because $f(2)=-\sqrt{6}$ is indicated without additional specification (compare to 'the top side of the cut' in the pdf) so that the function must be smooth at point $z=2$. This point would indeed be on the cut had we chosen the cut outside of $(-1,0)$.

Here is a picture of the argument of your function as considered (the minus adds $\pi$ to the argument) :
[image: argument]

note that for $z$ real with $z<-1$ the arguments become equal to 0 $\pmod {2\pi}$

The same kind of problem was handled in this other [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150221/what-is-the-arg-of-sqrtt-1t-2-at-the-point-t-0/150693#150693) with the cut shown outside the points or inside. Note that there is a link to the handling of the general case at the end (just set a=−1 and b=0 there).

Comment: Alright, thanks. I see how the factorization works here. I still don't see why it works, though. 
If I'm just given that $f$ is an branch of $\sqrt{z^2+z}$ with $f(2) = -\sqrt{6}$, why does it factor to $-z\sqrt{1+1/z^2}$ (principal branch; $|z| >1$)? I know that this factorization is correct up to sign, and I can just check a value to verify the right sign; but that doesn't tell me why it's correct.

Comment: @ec92: because there are not many Laurent-series around $0$ corresponding : one with the $+$ sign the other with the $-$ sign. With $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+x}$ for example the powers of $x$ will be increasing (and 'half-powered') while the square root $z^2(1+1/z)$ will give us the decreasing integer powers that we want. Other 'adequate' formulations should give the same Laurent expansion at the end!

Comment: @ec92: "Because the Laurent expansion of a function is unique whenever it exists, any expression of this form that actually equals the given function $f(z)$ in some annulus must actually be the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$" Wiki [Laurent series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series).

Answer (score 0):

A function has a branch point $a$, if the function changes its value when the argument increases by $2 n \pi$, $n$ is an integer. That means, if you replace $z$ by $r e^{i w}$ in your function (change to polar coordinates), then replace $w$ by $w + 2 n \pi$, the function changes its value. If you do this you will see the minus sign ( or the other value of the function, since the function is discontinuous at the branch cut).